# Return different number of rows for the same section (depening on variable)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, rows

I have a tableview with 2 sections.

Section 1 has **1** row
Section 2 has either **1** or **2** rows depending on an integer

I tried something really simple, which should really work. But it doesn't:

```
if(section == 0)
    return 1;
else
    if(numberOfRows == 2)
            return 2;
    else
            return 1;
```

For now I will return 2 rows, no matter numberOfRows value.
Also, when I tried the exact same code but with curly brackets, it didn't work. How weird is that?

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint and stepping through this line by line to make sure the numberOfRows variable's value is what you think it should be?

Comment: "should work but doesn't" - that's kind of vague - what happens?  Also, what is "accolades {}"?

Comment: @ abizern I have, and it has the value I expected
@Rayfleck `if (section == 0) { return 1; }` does NOT work, `if (section == 0) return 1;` DOES work. Strange, right?

Comment: @svdv22 - can you please post the exact code you're running - maybe fresh eyes would help. (BTW, I **ALWAY** wrap if-blocks in {}'s. I've been burned and seen others burned too many times without them.  It's worth the discipline and effort.)

Comment: @Rayfleck I do that too. Even without the 'shift-reduce-conflict' reasoning Jenox was talking about, it just makes the code more readable. But as that wasn't working I tried without, and than strangely enough worked. Turns out the problem to my question lied within the fact my int wasn't an int after all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try writing it this way:

```
if(section == 0) return 1;
else if(numberOfRows == 2) return 2;
return 1;
```

I am proposing this based on your condition that you **only** have 2 sections not more.

Comment: Well this means that the state `numberOfRows == 2` is never happening and this means there is something wrong in your code (not in this function). Please provide more code so we can help. How are you controlling `numberOfRows`? Try `NSLog` these variables to see what is happening. Also maybe the `section` variable does not have correct value as you want it.

Comment: That led me right to the direction. There was something else wrong. For some reason my integer wasn't an int after all. So `if ([numberOfRows isEqualToString:@"1"]) {` worked like a charm. However in my .h file I declared it as an int. Quick houserule question: should I mark this as the correct answer, as it wasn't really the correct answer but did lead me to it?

Comment: hahaha, it is up to you, you can just raise it (meaning this answer was useful), or you can set it as correct since it was the road to it. Really it is up to you :D And happy for you that you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a [shift-reduce-conflict](http://docs.freebsd.org/info/bison/bison.info.Shift_Reduce.html).
I would recommend always using curly brackets!

Comment: Well, the way I understand that article the following code should work: `    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if (numberOfRows == 2) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }` It doesn't..

Comment: That has to work. Try calling -reloadData on the table view when you variable changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project and re-building everything, and running again.